# grep Print all Strings (Not Lines) that starts with the '(' , contains 'specific substring' , ends with ')'

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, grep

How can I print all Strings (Not Lines) that starts with the '(' character, contains a 'specific substring' and ends with ')' character using grep.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". Also please take the tour and read about how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution.  For example if I must print all strings that starts with the '(' ends with the ')' and contains 'blablabla' string:

```
grep -oh "[(][^\(\)]*blablabla[^\(\)]*[)]" dump.txt
```